# How to list group ids in GCP using cli or console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-groups-api

I would like to know is there any way to get group ids either using CLI or Cloud console? Using this id, I need to collect the members list using Cloud API. I was going through google documentation but I couldn't find it.

For example if I use:

```
gcloud identity groups memberships list --group-email=abc@xyz.com
```

It gives the group id. Then I am using [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups.memberships/list) to get the list of members.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/identity/groups/memberships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using Google's SDK tool `gcloud` is ok with you then you can do it as follows:

Group's ID is it's actual email address - you can see it below:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ $ gcloud identity groups describe esa111@google.com
createTime: '2021-10-12T09:13:16.737141Z'
description: test group
displayName: esa111
groupKey:
  id: esa111@google.com
labels:
  cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum: ''
name: groups/00rj4333f0glbwez
parent: customers/Cx2hsdde9nw
updateTime: '2021-10-12T09:13:16.737141Z'
```

To get a members list:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ $ gcloud identity groups memberships list --group-email=esa111@google.com
---
name: groups/00rj4333f0glbwez/memberships/129543432329845052
preferredMemberKey:
  id: esa222@google.com
roles:
- name: MEMBER
---
name: groups/00rj4333f0glbwez/memberships/11674834e3327905886
preferredMemberKey:
  id: esa111@google.com
roles:
- name: OWNER
- name: MEMBER
```

And to have just group's members ID's listed use `grep` and you'll get:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ $ gcloud identity groups memberships list --group-email=esa111@google.com | grep id:
  id: esa222@google.com
  id: esa111@google.com
```

Here's some docs on the [`gcloud identity groups describe`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/identity/groups/describe) and [`list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/identity/groups/memberships/list) commands.